# WPF custom fonts

Tags: wpf, fonts

I have used a custom font in my WPF application. The custom font works fine except for numbr 17 in which the 7 merges into 1. I thought the problem was with my fonts. So I checked it by testing it in a Java Swing project, a sample web application etc. There it works fine. How do I rectify this problem

Comment: Also this occurs only if the text is numeric.If its alpha numeric then it doesn't happens

Comment: This is the link of the font file:   http://ufonts.com/fonts/berthold-akzidenz-grotesk-be-condensed.html

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1 as platform

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me,

```
<Style x:Key="fontTest">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="/Fonts/#/Fonts/#Berthold Akzidenz Grotesk BE BoldCn"/>
        </Style>
</Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="74*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="429*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock  Text="17 this is a test"  FontSize="26"  FontFamily="Adobe Kaiti Std" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,48,0"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock  Text="1 7 this is a test"  FontSize="26"  Style="{DynamicResource fontTest}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,51,48,0"/>       
    </Grid
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: change the text to "17". and then test it,it will not work.only 17 and no other characters

Comment: The font is not applied man.Replace the value of setter with this:"#Berthold Akzidenz Grotesk BE BoldCn" with correct path name

Comment: yes you are right! add a space between 1 and 7, then its fine

Comment: check my above message!

Comment: This may work for static texts but for dynamic texts it would be too much of trouble. Same issue for retrieving the value in the back-end